# Module receiving / for empty (no path) requests

Tags: apache, http, url, redirect

I'm working on an Apache module that helps me eliminate duplicate content but I have a problem retrieving a true value.

This is the basic most important function I can provide to make the module print a value and terminate regardless of the URL I visit.

```
static int handler(request_rec *r){
  ap_rprintf(r,"%s\n",r->the_request);
  return DONE;
}
```

According to http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/apache_mod/128.htm, It states

> char *the_request
>   This contains the first line of the request, for logging purposes.

I then ran some tests on a local server at `http://127.0.0.1:81`

When I execute on the command line:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:81/
```

I receive the following:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

When I execute on the command line:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:81
```

I receive the following:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Why does the_request always return `GET / HTTP/1.1` instead of `GET / HTTP/1.1` and `GET  HTTP/1.1`?

I want to create a redirection from `http://127.0.0.1:81` to `http://127.0.0.1:81/` so google or other search engines don't think I have duplicate content.

When I changed my code to:

```
static int handler(request_rec *r){
ap_rprintf(r,"%s\n",r->unparsed_uri);
return DONE;
}
```

I still have problems because I'm expecting a `/` and a null from trying `http://127.0.0.1:81/` and `http://127.0.0.1:81` respectively.

I suspect theres a bug in HTTP or apache but I want to know if theres anything I can do to fix this.

I want accesses to `http://127.0.0.1:81` to return a 301 redirect status with the location pointing to `http://127.0.0.1:81/`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the_request always return GET / HTTP/1.1 instead of GET /
>   HTTP/1.1 and GET  HTTP/1.1?

HTTP requires a path in the request URL. Clients often let you omit it (along with the scheme), but on the wire they're always adding it back for you.  It's just a convenience that you can type "example.com" in a browser, it doesn't mean there's no path or scheme associated with it.